# C# Razor Pages app cannot access route data

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm new to C# and .net but recently started a Razor Pages app using the dotnet cli `dotnet new webapp ...`. Everything has been running smoothly until I've tried to access route data from the URL.

What I want is to have a search result page at `/search/{search_term}`. And i want to be able to access the search_term in my `PageModel`.

Here is my current PageModel located at `APP_ROOT/Pages/Search/Index.cshtml.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ChowderForkWeb.Service;
using ChowderForkWeb.Model;

namespace MyApp.Pages;

public class SearchModel : PageModel
{
    public List<Post> posts = new();

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string Term { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
      var svc = new PostService();
      posts = svc.Search(Term);
    }
}
```

The top of my cshtml file looks like this and is located at `APP_ROOT/Pages/Search/Index.cshtml`

```
@page
@model SearchModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Search";
}
```

This is working well if the term is part of the query params in the URL (`/search?term=foo`) but does not work if I try to access `/search/foo`. I have tried updating the `@page` statement in my .cshtml file to `@page "{ term }"` as many articles have suggested but the search term is not being passed to the PageModel.

Any suggestions for how I can make this work?

Comment: `@page "{ term }"` should be `@page "{term}"`

Comment: Oh! I see. I didn't realize it was sensitive to white case. This worked for me. Thank you!